Account to Contact relationship - wasn't able to insert Account Object to Permset without Contact
I know that when it comes to master-detail relationship there is need to find all the masters before. I did it and it'd been working fine before.But when it comes to Account-Contact - i always get kinda

Database.UpsertResult[getErrors=(Database.Error[getFields=();getMessage=Permission Read Account depends on permission(s): Read Contact;getStatusCode=FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION;]);getId=null;isCreated=true;isSuccess=false

for(FieldDefinition def : [SELECT  
        QualifiedApiName,
        EntityDefinitionId,
        EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName
    FROM FieldDefinition 
    WHERE EntityDefinitionId in :entries
        and Datatype like 'Master-%' ]) { 
        String[] tempo = mdEntityFields.get(def
            .EntityDefinition
            .QualifiedApiName);
        if(tempo == null) {
            mdEntityFields.put(def
                .EntityDefinition
                .QualifiedApiName, 
                new String[]{def.QualifiedApiName});
        } else {
            tempo.add(def.QualifiedApiName);
        }
        entityDefinitions.add(def.EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName); 
    } 


Can you share code snippet you are using

updated my question with code snippet

looks like account to contact rel has lookup, but CascadeDelete matters

is it possible to detect somehow if 2 objects have CascadeDelete?
